# Remove '/' from end of variable - bash

Tags: bash

I'm looking to remove the '/' from the end of a variable so I can check if a file is a symlink to a directory. I've tried just about every method I could think of or find online, is there something I'm missing?

If I check if a file is a symlink with the '/' on the end, it treats it as a directory. This can be checked by running:

```
if [ -L symtest/ ] ; then echo "symlink"; fi
```

where symtest is a symlink to a directory. The above outputs nothing.

When I remove the '/', it works fine and outputs "symlink":

```
if [ -L symtest ] ; then echo "symlink"; fi
```

My question is, is there a way to remove the '/' from the name when it's passed as a variable to a function?

The function would look something like:

```
function is_it_a_symlink() {
    if [ -L $1 ] ; then
        echo "This file is a symlink!"
    else
        echo "This file is not a symlink!"
    fi
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that POSIX's [Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13) rules require the behaviour you observe.

Comment: @Alexander, please avoid linking the ABS as a resource -- it has a longstanding reputation of showcasing bad practices. (Using the gratuitous `function` keyword -- which breaks compatibility with POSIX sh but adds no value over the standardized function declaration syntax -- is onesuch).

Comment: @Alexander, ...actually, there are more serious bad practices in that particular page you linked as well. `directorys=$@` loses boundary information -- one can't distinguish between `./yourscript "foo bar" "baz qux"` and `./yourscript foo bar baz qux` after using it; the `linkchk` function is missing quotes (needs to be `"$1"/*` and `linkchk "$element"`), and more.

Comment: @Alexander, ...a better link for `test` operators is http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest; another reliable resource is the Wooledge wiki, ie. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. There's also the POSIX specification for `test` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I will look into those links.

Comment: @PhilipGibbons, btw, http://shellcheck.net/ is a useful resource -- it would have pointed out the missing quoting for you, for instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good to know, I wasn't aware of that site. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX-ly, using parameter expansion to get rid of the last `/`:

```
${parameter%/}
```

So, your case:

```
[ -L "${1%/}" ]
```

---

External tool, `sed`:

```
sed 's_/$__' <<<"$1"
```

So:

```
[ -L "$(sed 's_/$__' <<<"$1")" ]
```

---

Similarly, `awk`:

```
awk '{sub("/$", "")} 1' <<<"$1"
```

So:

```
[ -L "$(awk '{sub("/$", "")} 1' <<<"$1")" ]
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I had actually tried that earlier just without the quotation marks. Thanks!

Comment: To be safe, you should probably remove *all* trailing `/`; don't assume there is just one. `${1%%/}`

Comment: @chepner, ...that works? I thought one had to use an extglob to match a sequence there. Actually, it looks to me like one does; thus, `${1%%+(/)}`, after `shopt -s extglob`.